# Retrofit cache expires itself after 24 Hours

Tags: android, retrofit

I am trying to create an android app which will fetch data from internet using Retrofit. I have made retrofit caching system too. I works fine for 24 Hours since the app went offline but after 24 Hours all the stored cache data expire itself.
I even changed the expiration time inside code from **60 * 60 * 20 (1 day)** to **60 * 60 * 24 * 185 (185 days)**. Is there any solution?

```
public class RetrofitInstance {
    private static final String BASE_URL = "DOMAIN_HERE";

    public static Retrofit getRetrofit(Context context)
    {
            File httpCacheDirectory = new File(context.getCacheDir(), "httpCache");
            Cache cache = new Cache(httpCacheDirectory, 10 * 1024 * 1024);

            OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                    .cache(cache)
                    .addInterceptor(chain -> {
                        try {
                            return chain.proceed(chain.request());
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Request offlineRequest = chain.request().newBuilder()
                                    .header("Cache-Control", "public, only-if-cached," +
                                            "max-stale=" + 60 * 60 * 24 * 185)
                                    .build();
                            return chain.proceed(offlineRequest);
                        }
                    })
                    .build();

        return new Retrofit.Builder()
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(new Gson()))
            .client(httpClient)
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .build();
    }

}
```

Comment: show me your code for Retrofit cache settings

Comment: @RutvikBhatt code added.. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps.
1) Try forcing the Cache-control

```
 .cacheControl(CacheControl.FORCE_CACHE)
```

after

```
 Request offlineRequest = chain.request().newBuilder()
```

or
 2)

```
 Request request = new Request.Builder()
   .cacheControl(new CacheControl.Builder()
       .maxStale(365, TimeUnit.DAYS)
         .build();
```

Documentation: https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/Cache.html

Comment: Thank you, @Rizwan sir.